# Is Flutter app data preserved on reinstallation?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Is Flutter app data preserved if the user uninstalls and installs the app again?

How to make the data preserved on reinstallation?

How to make the data not preserved on reinstallation?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your data not to be preserved upon reinstallation, then you have two options - using shared preferences or the internal storage(app specific storage).
But in case you want your data to be preserved after reinstallation, then you should use the external storage, but this will be accessed by every application installed on the device.